# how can I fetch the value in html file I used entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, model-view-controller

I wrote this below code on controller section

```
DateTime start = student.Timestamp;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{

}
DateTime end = student.Endstamp;
```

How can I fetch the value `start` and `end` Variable in the `cshtml` file(text box)  ?

Please note that I am using in Entity Framework.

Comment: Add your code to the question that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **viewbag** to get values from a controller to view. e.g:

*In controller*

```
Public ActionResult Index(){
    ...
    ViewBag.start = student.Timestamp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
    {
       //your code 
    }
    ViewBag.end = student.Endstamp;
    ...
    return View();
}
```

*In View index.cshtml*

```
<input type="text" id="txtStart" value="@ViewBag.start" />
<input type="text" id="txtEnd" value="@ViewBag.end" />
```

or

```
<p>this is start: @ViewBag.start</p>
<p>this is end: @ViewBag.End</p>
```

Comment: where you write the above code? In Get action of controller while loading?

Comment: controller:                                                                                                                   ViewBag.start = start;
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
      { }
   ViewBag.End = end; is it correct?

Comment: I modified the answer.

Comment: i tried modified code also but still it is not working

Comment: start time and end time it is not displaying front end side.

Comment: Can you post the class definition of your student object? What is the type of Timestamp property?

Comment: how can I improve bulk operation performance when I inserted 1lack record its taking 110mins I am using entity framework